# Preinititalize a map in C++

Tags: c++

I need a class to have a `const std::map` from string to pointer to a function. How can I initialize this map without adding elements like this:

```
string func1(string a){
    return a;
}

string func2(string x){
    return "This is a random string";
}

//In class declaration:
   const map<string,string(*)(string)> a;

//Where should this go? Any other, probably better method to initialize this map?
    a["GET"] = &func1;
    a["SET"] = &func2;
```

EDIT:

I am doing this on pre-C++11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would a std::map extended initializer list look like?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250123/what-would-a-stdmap-extended-initializer-list-look-like)

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, I didnt mention that I'm not using C++1y.

Comment: You only need C++11.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way I used to do this pre-C++11 was to create a function that returns the map and initialise my `const` variable using that function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string(*)(std::string)> MyMap;

std::string forward(std::string s) { return s; }
std::string backward(std::string s) { std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end()); return s; }

MyMap Init()
{
    MyMap map;
    map["forward"] = &forward;
    map["backward"] = &backward;
    return map;
}

const MyMap Map = Init(); // <--- initialise map via function

int main()
{
    for (MyMap::const_iterator iter = Map.begin(); iter != Map.end(); iter++)
        std::cout << (*iter->second)(iter->first) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/DPvzUB)