# What does this map initialization mean in C++ STL?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, unordered-map

```
int numSubarraysWithSum(vector<int>& A, int S) {
    unordered_map<int, int> c({{0, 1}});// Line 1
    int psum = 0, res = 0;
    for (int i : A) {
        psum += i;
        res += c[psum - S];
        c[psum]++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

What does line 1 mean? I'm confused as there are two curly braces.

Comment: Initialiser list as mentioned in [given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67732420/1312382). The outer braces define the initialiser list itself, the inner braces are shorthand for constructing `std::pair`s, which are used in the map to store the keys and corresponding values.

Comment: You might see the same construct leaving out the (round) parentheses, which is legal (uniform initialisation – which is done for the inner pairs, too), but I cannot recommend this in general (and especially not in templates), as there are situations where the wrong constructor can be chosen, e. g. `std::vector<int> v{7, 3}` uses the initialiser list constructor, but you might have wanted to select [third variant of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). This is especially critical for classes in development if the initialiser list constructor is added later on.

Comment: So my personal recommendation is to prefer the classic constructor call (round parentheses as you've seen already) over uniform initialisation: `std::vector v(7, 3)` (three sevens) vs. `std::vector v({7, 3})` (one seven, one three) is just so much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

It's something called an `Initilizer list`. According to [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/):

> Initializer List is used in initializing the data members of a class.
> The list of members to be initialized is indicated with constructor as
> a comma-separated list followed by a colon.

Basically it adds elements into your `std::map` (or in this case your `std::unordered_map`) right while you're creating it.

More specifically, from @Aconcagua comment above :

> The outer braces define
> the `initializer list` itself, the inner braces are shorthand for
> constructing `std::pair`s, which are used in the `std::map` to store the keys
> and corresponding values.

You can see this from this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, int> c({{0, 1}, {1, 7}});
    for (auto it = c.begin(); it!=c.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 1
1 7
```

There's also other data types that support this, for example `std::vector` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> test({0, 7, 9, 11, 3});
    for (auto x : test) {cout << x << "\n";}
}
```

Output:

```
0
7
9
11
3
```

There's a lot of question regarding this:

- [Initializing a static std::map<int, int> in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138600/initializing-a-static-stdmapint-int-in-c)
- [What would a std::map extended initializer list look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250123/what-would-a-stdmap-extended-initializer-list-look-like)

And more info: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

*Cautions : As @Aconcagua mentioned below, [`using namespace std` is not considered a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), although it might save some typing time.

Comment: Considering that all occurs right in the constructor I'd replace `right after you created it` with `right while creating it`. Even though apparently question author did so, I wouldn't apply `using namespace std` in my own answers for [good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Apart from, nice answer.

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks for the comment, I'll modified my answer and add the `using namespace std;` cautions.

Answer (score 0):

It simply just add elements into your map. There are many different ways to do this:

1. `unordered_map<int, int> c{ {0, 1} };`  similar to your question

2  `unordered_map<int, int> c;`
`c[0]=1`;
assign key and value

3.

```
 unordered_map<int, int> c;
       c.insert(std:: make_pair (key, vale) );  use make_pair
```

... You can refer more here    [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250123/what-would-a-stdmap-extended-initializer-list-look-like)

Comment: There's a difference, though, in between 1. and 2./3.: First variant initialises the map directly, allocating sufficient memory right away, while the other two variants first create an empty, default initialised map and only then request the memory. which is (slightly) less efficient.

Comment: I do not recommend leaving out the round parentheses around initaliser lists, see my comments to question. Some might contradict, though, so make up your own mind ;)